# What do the "Corr" values under random effects section of the nlme output mean?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

When I want to analyze longitudinal data with few observations, I implement it in the following way:

```
fitL.sl <- lme(YL ~ timeL, random = ~ timeL | subjL, data = dataL)
summary(fitL.sl)
```

Here, I want to model Y with respect to time (4 measurement time-points) and allow both the intercepts and slopes for the subjects to be random. When I do so, I obtain the following output for the random effects:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
Data: dataL 
   AIC      BIC    logLik
  111.0408 122.6296 -40.52041

Random effects:
 Formula: ~timeL | subjL
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parameterization
            StdDev    Corr                
(Intercept) 8.7606657 (Intr) timeL2 timeL3
timeL2      3.6191748 -0.743              
timeL3      5.7531254 -0.943  0.487       
timeL4      5.5406171 -0.345  0.227  0.425
Residual    0.2253594
```

What exactly does the "Corr" section (right to the StdDev) refer to? At first, I thought that it is intraclass correlation but not sure about this. I also looked for other examples but could not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Corr` is a lower triangular matrix containing the estimated correlations between the random effects.

For example, the correlation between the random intercept and the random slope for `timeL2` is -0.743, while the correlation between the randome slope for `timeL3` and the random slope for `timeL4` is 0.425, and so on.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your reply.

Comment: But if there is one random effect (say random intercepts but fixed slopes), how should I interpret it? Then there will be only one random effect. Is it like the correlation between random intercepts over time? But it pertains to first measurement time...

Comment: You're welcome. If there is only a single random effect, eg random intercepts, and no random slopes, then `Corr` will be absent from the output.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense :)